# Multisite theme path rewrite using .htaccess

Tags: theme-development, url-rewriting, htaccess, rewrite-rules

I'm trying to rewrite the theme path for multiple domains (wordpresss multisite) using separate themes, this is my current .htaccess file, this is allowing each site to use seperate CSS files but not img,js or fonts.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^multisite1.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*) /wp-content/themes/multisite1/css/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*) /wp-content/themes/multisite1/js/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^img/(.*) /wp-content/themes/multisite1/img/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fonts/(.*) /wp-content/themes/multisite1/fonts/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^multisite2.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^img/(.*) /wp-content/themes/multisite2/img/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*) /wp-content/themes/multisite2/css/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*) /wp-content/themes/multisite2/js/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fonts/(.*) /wp-content/themes/multisite2/fonts/$1 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^multisite3.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*) /wp-content/themes/multisite3/css/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*) /wp-content/themes/multisite3/js/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^img/(.*) /wp-content/themes/multisite3/img/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^fonts/(.*) /wp-content/themes/multisite3/fonts/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^plugins/(.*) /wp-content/plugins/$1 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? You can already use different themes on different domain of multisite. It is an already built in functionality.

Comment: Hi Sisir, I'm trying to hide the path to the theme directory, so multisite3.com/wp-content/themes/multisite3/css/  will become  multisite3.com/css/